# Use dplyr syntax with Mongo DB

Tags: r, mongodb, dplyr, tidyverse

Is it possible, with mongolite or another R package to use dplyr syntax to query a MongoDB? I was thinking something like:

```
library(mongolite)

# create collection with example data
dmd <- mongo("diamonds")
dmd$insert(ggplot2::diamonds)
```

Attempt to query using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

premium_diamonds <- dmd %>%
   filter(cut == "Premium",
            price < 1000)
```

instead of this:

```
premium_diamonds <- dmd$find('{"cut" : "Premium", "price" : { "$lt" : 1000 } }')
```

This way I could use my familiarity with dplyr to make complex queries.

Comment: technically yes, if you connect to mongoDB using Spark & the `sparklyr` package, but this may be overkill for your usecase.